# Altering checkboxes rendering in a form

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I've a drupal website with a custom theme based on [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen).

In a specific page of my website, I've a form rendered by the [Finder](http://drupal.org/project/finder) module (which uses the Drupal Form API).

I want to modify the way Drupal render the checkboxes of this particular form.

Let's say Drupal render my checkboxes like this :

```
<input type="checkbox"> Choice 1
```

I want to modify the html into something like :

```
<input type="checkbox">
    Choice 1        
    <div></div>
```

This could allow me to better adjust the layout using CSS.

Can someone point me the right direction to achieve this ?

**Solution :**

Since the finder outputs Checkboxes (and not many Checkbox), using #field_suffix didn't solve my problem. 
Why ? 
Because applying the following code :

```
$form['finder_form']['type']['#field_suffix'] = "<div>field suffix</div>";
```

Results in this :

```
<div class="form-checkboxes>
    <div>
        <input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input>
    </div>
    <div class="suffix"></div>
</div>
```

So I ended up doing :

```
foreach ($form['finder_form']['type']['#options'] as $key => $value) {
    $form['finder_form']['type']['#options'][$key] = $value." <div class='suffix'></div>";        
}
```

If a better approach is found, I will edit this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input element has no close tag, so this is not really a well-formed question.

That said, what you are probably looking for is [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) which you would implement in your own custom module to alter this particular form element.

Have a look at the [#field_suffix propery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#field_suffix) for how you could append some arbitrary markup to your element.

Comment: I've edited my question regarding the input tags. And This seems the right way to go. I will take a closer look.